# Is there an optimal message size when streaming over grpc?

Tags: grpc

I have a way to control message size when I stream the data through grpc. Unfortunately I am not able to find info on what would be optimal message size. I found [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc.github.io/issues/371) but it is not resolved.

Is keeping it under 4MB threshold good enough or there are some guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on your application needs, network configuration, and language. Messages around 16-64K are perhaps best suited for the most wide variety of configurations including mobile etc. For pure throughput-oriented workloads in data centers we regularly see GB sized messages, but 1 MB messages are perhaps pretty close to ideal tradeoff of minimal computational overhead and immediate memory capacity needs for the amount of network pipelining that they provide.