# Performance implicaton for grpc max message size

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

In grpc bidirectional mode, there is a way to setup message max size on grpc channel args for client and server. What are the performance implications of this setting, since message size is dynamic, would there be any performance impact setting size to 4MB vs unlimited?

Internally, how this message size parameter is used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an optimal message size when streaming over grpc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195598/is-there-an-optimal-message-size-when-streaming-over-grpc)